# JSON API implmentation for service object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api

As you know, service object is used to create data for multiple domains, or connect 3rd party APIs in one procedure.

So in this case, resource interface and domain model are not exactly matched.

For example, you want to create Subscription.
The procedure is following,

1. create User
2. create choose the Plan
3. create Subscription (connecting third party API)

*(If something fails, the rollback occurs.)*

The business logic is across more than one domain.
So I could do POST with those JSON data.

```
{"plan_id": 1,
 "user_info":{"uuid": "644e1dd7-2a7f-18fb-b8ed-ed78c3f92c2b",
              "name": "John Doe",
              "email": "john@gmailcom"},
 "user_card_info": {"object":"card",
                    "exp_month": 12,
                    "exp_year": 2020,
                    "number": 4242424242424242}
 }
```

In this case, how should I handle this situation in JSON API.
Maybe Should I create `abstract resource`?
Also How can I handle this within Controller in JSON API?

Answer (score 0):

To do this in the front end, you would essentially need to duplicate rails validations for every single field, however it is much simpler to do this in rails within the controller action.

Firstly, all relevant models need to have the proper validations (generic and custom if necessary). This way, when you create an invalid object, you can catch the issue. Then, there's a class method called `#transactions`. I've listed the documentation below. This allows you to insert multiple records at once and rollback if any of them fail which should solve your issue. Be sure to use the `#save!` method over `#save` because the latter fails silently. Hopefully this was helpful :)

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: What about third party API request?

Comment: What about third party API request? Could you be more clear on what the third party API request is requesting as well as what you want your API to do?